# Blocking Google (and other search engines) from crawling domain

Tags: web, dns, seo, search-engine

We want to open a new domain for certain purposes (call them PR). The thing is we want the domain to point to the same website we currently have.

We do not want this new domain to appear on search engines (specifically Google) at all.

Options we've ruled out:

- Robots.txt can't be used - it will work the same on both domains, which isn't what we want.
- [The `rel=canonical`](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) doesn't block - only suggests to index a similar page instead. The original page might end up being indexed.

Is there a way to handle this?

**EDIT**

Regarding `.htaccess` suggestions: we're on IIS7.

Comment: I know you've mentioned that Robots.txt can't be used because it will be used on both domains, which is False.

Could you expand your reason?

Comment: I would expect that if `newdomain.com` proxies `olddomain.com`, the same `robots.txt` would appear under both domains unless it is generated dynamically.

Comment: @Torxed, I don't know that Robots.txt can be generated dynamically. Since we're talking of the same physical location - there is only one file.

Comment: @JNF the robots.txt file can be quite dynamic and there shouldn't be any issues allowing one domain and blocking the other from robots.
But then again, this is, if you trust that google doesn't index your site based on a simple text file located on your root...
If i were to write a bot, i'd skip robots.txt all togeather.. I would make sure that your useragent is blocked via .htaccess or something similar.. but that's just me..

Comment: → http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43234/block-google-and-other-from-indexing-a-domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rel=canonical` is *not* a suggestion. It tells Google exactly which page to use.

Having said that, when serving pages that are in the domain you do not want indexed you can use the [`x-robots-tag- to block those pages from being indexed:](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html)

> Simply add any supported META tag to a new X-Robots-Tag directive in
>   the HTTP Header used to serve the file.
>
> Don't include this document in the Google search results:

`X-Robots-Tag: noindex`

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't know about this tag. To solve this problem, it would need to be conditional on the request domain, but since it would be included at the same level as the proxy or redirect to the original domain that should be pretty simple.

Comment: It's a great way to make sure an admin section of a website is never indexed without having to list it in robots.txt which tells hackers where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [setting your preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools?](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066&topic=2371375&ctx=topic#1)

The drawback to this approach is that it doesn't work for other search engines.

Comment: That's only for subdomains.

Comment: That has not been my experience with sites using multiple domain names interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

I would block via say a .htaccess file on the domain in question at the root of the site.

```
BrowserMatchNoCase SpammerRobot bad_bot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

Where you'd have to specify the different bots used by the major search engines.
Or you could allow all known webbrowsers and white list them instead.